# PostgreSQL - restoring one table from database dump

Tags: postgresql

How can I restore one table from database dump ? I make dump using the next command:

```
pg_dump -U admin -h localhost my-db-name | gzip - > /home/a2_db_backup/my-db-name-backup.sql.gz
```

Comment: you can only do a selective restore if you use `pg_dump` with the custom or directory format. You can do that with a "plain text" (SQL script) dump.

Comment: As horse says; use different `pg_dump` options, like this: https://dev.to/andyatkinson/dump-and-load-a-postgresql-table-p0o

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no easy way, except for some hacks (like using awk to cut the part of the file).

If the dump is not too big, the easiest thing to do is restore the full backup to a temporary database (`gzcat backup_file.gz | psql -h host -U user database_name`) dump the one table (`pg_dump -t my_table`), then restore it.

---

For future reference, the custom and directory [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) formats do allow restoring a single table. Use either of the following commands to create dumps:

```
pg_dump -Fc database_name > database.dump
```

or

```
pg_dump -Fd database_name -f database.dump
```

`-Fd` produces a directory, but this doesn't affect the [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) command; just use the same name that you specified for the dump output. See [`pg_dump` man page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) for the details - especially the [examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-EXAMPLES) at the end.

Then you can use [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) to restore a single table:

```
pg_restore -t my_table -d database_name database.dump
```

Comment: Is it restores full database? I need only a single table.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the accepted answer, you could use awk to cut the file like so:

```
awk '/COPY public.<tablename>/,/\\./' dump_file.sql > restore_table.sql
```

and then restore using psql:

```
psql [...] < restore_table.sql
```

Obviously, this only works if the table has been truncated and not dropped.