# PostgreSQL - restoring one backup table from database dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

My PowerShell current directory is the backup directory/folder.
I use `pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -t emp > empbackup.sql` to backup one specific table. I aslo use `pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -t emp > empbackup.dump`.
Now I want to restore this table to the database. `emp` table is no foreign key, primary key, totally isolated table.
I tried serval ways. All failed. related question: [PostgreSQL - restoring one table from database dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508704/postgresql-restoring-one-table-from-database-dump)

```
pg_restore -t emp -d postgres empbackup.sql
```

**Error** pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres  -f empbackup.sql
```

**Error** --psql:empbackup.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ÿ_"
--LINE 1: ÿ_-

```
pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres -d postgres  -t     public.emp  --verbose "C:\Users\JIAN HE\Desktop\pg\empbackup.sql"
```

**Error**  --pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

```
pg_restore -t emp -d postgresql empbackup.dump
```

**Error** pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Comment: Nope. I don't know how to compress...

Answer (score 0):

The y with the dots is a misinterpretation of a UTF byte order marker (BOM)

In my hands, `psql -f file` on powershell doesn't know how to deal with these,  but on a pipe it does (Or they just don't get written on a pipe)

```
type empbackup.sql | psql -U postgres -d postgres
```